# Adding unique values

Tags: excel, sumifs

Community,

In Excel, I am trying to add values that are unique only. This is an example:

```
Acct #             Value$
9xxx123            40
9xxx123            15
9xxx123            40
9xxx123            21
9xxx123            15
9xxx234            10
9xxx234            08
9xxx234            10
```

My data has repeated values and I am trying to only add the unique values for the same accounts. For example, on the data above my answer should look like:

```
9xxx123 = 76
9xxx234 = 18
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((($A$2:$A$9=E2)*$B$2:$B$9)/(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$9,E2,$B$2:$B$9,$B$2:$B$9)+($A$2:$A$9<>E2)))
```

[image]

Comment: Never disappoint.

Comment: Thanks! it works perfectly!

Comment: @Leo Please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: I know that is an addition to the original post, but  what if I wanted to filter out one of the values. E.g. If dont' need to add value 10

Comment: @Leo New Questions deserve New Posts.  Please ask a new question.  Make sure you show how you tried to modify the above.